# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm always getting either this error, or "No Persistence provider" no matter what combination of dependencies and persistence.xml configurations I try.

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="LibraryJPA">
        <class>model.Clan</class>
        <class>model.Kategorija</class>
        <class>model.Knjiga</class>
        <class>model.Primerak</class>
        <class>model.Zaduzenje</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/biblioteka"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="something"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and this is pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>LibraryJPA</groupId>
    <artifactId>LibraryJPA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.40</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm looking for someone to help me why this doesn't work, and also how my pom.xml and persistence.xml should be set in order to make this work.